# How to read multi module maven project information(like dependencies) separately with maven-project plugin

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, mojo

I'm trying to read POM information(dependencies) from multi module maven project. This maven project contains other maven project for which i have to read separately.
I am using maven-project-2.2.1.jar to read the information. With this MavenProject project gets initialized with the parent maven project and it gives me the artifacts of all the project inside it.

But i need to read it seperately the maven projects. Below is my project structure

[image]

Here I can read fmg POM but i am not able to read FMGModules which is having common and FMG Managers.

Comment: What exactly are you trying? Apart from that why using such an old version of maven-project?

Comment: Actually, I want to create different docker images for dependencies based on some category(internal,external,e.t.c). Yeah, I know it's old, because we haven't done much development for this project. However I don't mind upgrading it.

Comment: I see an entry `localrepo` I hope it is not what I think it is? You are using Maven so the dependencies are downloaded via Maven... If you have special artifacts start using a repository manager ... furthermore a docker image for dependencies makes not really sense usually you should go for a docker image with prefilled dependencies of `$HOME/.m2/repository` which reduces things like that... the question is what kind of application will be built at the end?

Comment: `localrepo` is where we are keeping our libraries. So we are building different docker images based on some filters for different products. It will be helpful for our product. So we need to figure out the different modules of project from this plugin. Can we do this? I have spent a lot of time

Comment: Why do you have a `localrepo` within your project which contains your libraries? Not using the default local cache? What exactly is what you like to achieve? Just build docker images? Then why so complicated? That's easier makeable... Unfortunately not enough details to make a good suggestion...

Comment: Local repo we have customized for our projects. Not using as of now local cache.

Some background. My org is product based org. We have developed our framework(we call it as CORE) as per our business. Now we have different customer for which we have different projects which uses CORE as their framework.

Now we have to find out, how many libraries(self developed) CORE is having, how many external libraries CORE is using. Same way how many Project level libraries and how many Project level external libraries.

Comment: This we are doing as per our org standards( not sure about overall picture). So for this i need to read Maven projects. 
Hope it would give some details.

Comment: Define core (may be with several modules) as separate project build and release it via default model in Maven (versioning via https://semver.org). The core now defines it's dependencies and you can identify which is external and which is self made (other proejcts in your company) ... No each customer a separate project which uses core as a dependency (default machenisms) ..based on that you know already who is using which version of core (look into the pom file) easy to solve. From my point of view it looks like you are violating the idea of Maven and it's capabilities...